# Can you count the distinct cells from two columns in two tables?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two data sets:

- Public instagram channels (where followers_count lives)
- public sponsored instagram posts (where influencer_starting_followers lives)

i want to get the count # of cells that fall within the range of micro, mid, macro & celebrity from both tables.

however, right now with the query i have below, it's pulling the exact same number for both, which should not be the case.

any ideas what i've done wrong?

```
select (case when followers_count < 25000 then 'micro'
 when followers_count BETWEEN 25001 AND 100000 then 'mid'
when followers_count BETWEEN 100001 AND 499999  then 'macro'
else 'Celebrity'
end) as CreatorSize, 
count(distinct followers_count) as TotalBase,
count (distinct influencer_starting_followers) as PaidBase,
(sum(average_likes + average_comments)/ sum(followers_count)) as ER, 
(sum(likes + comments + video_views)/sum(influencer_starting_followers)) as paidER,
from  `public_instagram_channels` p
JOIN `public_sponsored_instagram_posts` as psip
ON psip.influencer_id=p.influencer_id
group by CreatorSize
```

Public_instagram_channels

| followers_count | average_likes | average_comments | influencer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 200 | 50 | 1234 |
| 1000 | 200 | 50 | 5678 |

Public_sponsored_instagram_posts

| influencer_starting_followers | likes | comments | video_views | influencer_id |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 200 | 50 | 20 | 1234 |
| 1000 | 200 | 50 | 20 | 1234 |

Desired outcome:
Public_sponsored_instagram_posts

| Creator Size | TotalBase | ER | PaidBase | PaidER |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Micro | 200 | 1% | 20 | 2% |
| Mid | 200 | 2% | 20 | 2% |
| Macro | 200 | 3% | 20 | 2% |
| Celebrity | 100 | 4% | 20 | 2% |

thanks for the help :)

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and a clear explanation of the logic you want to implement.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head I think I see two problems:

1. By specifying JOIN you are getting only the Influencer_ids that have records in BOTH tables.  It seems like you may want a FULL OUTER JOIN.  Ask yourself what if I'm in Table A and not B & vice versa.
2. Why are you counting distinct counts?  It seems like you want to be counting people who qualify to be in different categories.  Also summing averages is almost always wrong.

I think this is why Gordon Linoff asked for more clarification.